# After Effects: How to make text changes not affect width?

Tags: text, adobe-after-effects

Using After Effects, I am trying to do a countdown of 5 minutes with a setup like this: 5m 00s, 4m 59s, 4m 58s... I have the countdown already set up with Slider Control. However, I'm trying to use a mask for each character separately, which I also mostly have under control, except I realized that the text moves when the width of the text box changes as the text changes, for example, 2m 00s vs 1m 59s because of the width of the character "1" is smaller than "2" in the font I am using. Is there a way I can make the text box width, specifically each character's placement, not change even while Slider is in use? I have already gotten started on creating changes to the mask each time it changes, but I have a feeling it will be a lot of work.

Comment: Why not just use a mono-spaced font?

Comment: Video questions are often better handled at http://video.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Tetsujin I did consider it, but I'm just in love with Mont...

Comment: Then you'll have to put up with the numbers jumping around ;)

Comment: @Scott Thank you! I guess I misunderstood what the AE tag was for, my apologies

Comment: The tag is somewhat of a remnant from *before* the video stack existed. `:)` Or for questions related to cross-application issues with more design related software.